# How can I remove the gaps between the images for my nav bar?

Tags: html, css, html-table

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav_container" align="center">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/home.png" height="50" width="125"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/free/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/free.png" height="50" width="125"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/paid/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/paid.png" height="50" width="125"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/about-us/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/about-us.png" height="50" width="125"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/mission/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/mission.png" height="50" width="125"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav_container{
    background-color: #101010;
    height: 55px;
    width: 650px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the gap I want to remove. (The navigation bar and logo images are just placeholders. The black background behind the navigation bar images are there to better show the gap.)

[image]

Comment: Try adding `border-spacing: 0` or `border-collapse: collapse;` to the `table`. Besides, using `<table>` for navigation is not a good idea, you'd better use list elements — something like `<ul>` wrapped in a `<nav>`.

Comment: Start by writing correct markup. You have a list of links. It isn't tabular data.

Answer (score 1):

Use css instead of images inline styling and table

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
body{padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100vh;margin-top: 40px; text-align: center}
nav, nav a{display: inline-block;}
nav{
  background: black
}
nav a{
  color: white;
  background: red;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 10px 14px
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav id=nav_container>
    <a>home</a>
    <a>free</a>
    <a>paid</a>
    <a>about us</a>
    <a>mission</a>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Please note that `<main>` element is not designed to contain navigations. It should contain the most important/unique contents within the page.

Comment: I'm actually going down your route of not using images and using text after some thought. I'll just use a type face to make the text look more pleasing.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the gaps between the cells you need to set three CSS rules:

```
#nav_container table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
#nav_container td {
    padding:0;
}
#nav_container img {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5cuhvvx0/)**

Note also that I removed the height on your table.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways :
In css :

```
border-spacing:0px;
```

In html :

```
<table cellspacing="0"></table
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Since you're not using a CSS Reset, you may face other conflicts. I recommend using these styles to reset your table to work expectedly.

```css
/* CSS RESET */
html, body, body div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, menu, nav, section, time, mark, audio, video, details, summary {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    border-spacing: 0;
}
th {
    font-weight: bold; 
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
td {
    font-weight: normal; 
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* Your style */
#nav_container {
    background-color: #101010;
    height: 55px;
    width: 650px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_container" align="center">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> <a href="/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/home.png" height="50" width="125"></a>

            </td>
            <td> <a href="/free/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/free.png" height="50" width="125"></a>

            </td>
            <td> <a href="/paid/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/paid.png" height="50" width="125"></a>

            </td>
            <td> <a href="/about-us/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/about-us.png" height="50" width="125"></a>

            </td>
            <td> <a href="/mission/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/mission.png" height="50" width="125"></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**2.** Without CSS reset:
You need to add `border:0` and `inline-block` to `td` for the perfect adjustment.

```css
#nav_container {
    background-color: #101010;
    height: 55px;
    width: 650px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
td {
    border: 0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_container" align="center">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> <a href="/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/home.png" height="50" width="125"></a>

            </td>
            <td> <a href="/free/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/free.png" height="50" width="125"></a>

            </td>
            <td> <a href="/paid/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/paid.png" height="50" width="125"></a>

            </td>
            <td> <a href="/about-us/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/about-us.png" height="50" width="125"></a>

            </td>
            <td> <a href="/mission/"><img src="/assets/nav/buttons/mission.png" height="50" width="125"></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: There is something in the code that interferes with the center alignment of the navigation bar. So there is something in your code that needs to be added, removed, or modified to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of different ways to get this done.  I'm not a fan of tables for nav bars.  You could try using nav or ul.

```css
#nav_container {
  background-color: #101010;
  height: 55px;
  width: 650px;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}

#nav_bar img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_container" align="center">
  <nav id="nav_bar" nav_ba>
    <img src="/assets/nav/buttons/home.png" height="55" width="130">
    <img src="/assets/nav/buttons/home.png" height="55" width="130">
    <img src="/assets/nav/buttons/home.png" height="55" width="130">
    <img src="/assets/nav/buttons/home.png" height="55" width="130">
    <img src="/assets/nav/buttons/home.png" height="55" width="130">
  </nav>
</div>
```